# How to SSL Certificate file max size for an IE11 Browser?

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate, https, ssl-certificate-errors

At my work have a SSL Certificate file for web services.
this Certificate file size is over than 44K.

But seems like IE11 browser cannot parse or read a >44K SSL Certificate file. 
So IE11 Browser displayed like this message:

> Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://domaimhost again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site user an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details). which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator.
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5s10.png)

I've got checked a followed that guide message, but any problem like that message, even though Client and Server Cipher suits have been ECDH and DHE exactly matched both sides.

Therefore, let me suspicious this problem reason to Certificate file size has over than 44K.
Because that when I tried to this Certificate file size less to 43K(how to size less that is SAN list deleted some items.), IE11 Browser completely HTTPS contents displayed.

Please let me know that IE11 browser has SSL certificate limitation or Windows 7(SP1) have it.

Comment: 44kb certificate??? Why it's so big?

Comment: Because that so many alias domains  (more than 700) in this Cert SAN. This cert is MDC.

Comment: you really should reduce the size of certificate. I don't know about IE limitation on cert size, but I believe, that your design isn't very correct and you should not have so many DNS name aliases. Consider to reduce them by removing unused names and/or replacing with wildcards.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you. I have agreed that way, too. But it is so complicate on buisness side at  work

Comment: you should address your question to IE team or Microsoft Support.